# Only Stack Overflow has documentation, but the API erroneously lists documentation privileges for all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, api-v2.2, obsolete

Privileges related to [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) are displaying in every other site's API data.

Using *Meta Stack Exchange*, for example, [/2.2/privileges?site=meta](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#filter=default&site=meta&run=true) returns the following documentation related privileges.:

```
{
  "reputation": 15,
  "description": "Vote on documentation content",
  "short_description": "documentation votes"
},
...
{
  "reputation": 50,
  "description": "Comment on proposed changes and topic requests",
  "short_description": "documentation comments"
},
...
{
  "reputation": 100,
  "description": "Approve and reject proposed changes",
  "short_description": "documentation review"
},
...
```

But these are not available in the [Meta Stack Exchange Privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) because Meta Stack Exchange does not have the documentation feature.
Likewise [Stack Apps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true), [Web Applications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#filter=default&site=webapps&run=true), and every other site checked shows these false privileges in the API.

Since documentation only exists on Stack Overflow, please remove these false privileges from the other sites' APIs.